# Использовать СУБД или есть другие варианты?

Tags: база-данных, visual-c++

Пишу приложение, которое должно работать с таблицей из 4-ёх столбцов, содержащей ~1млн. записей. Целесообразно ли тут использовать СУБД наподобие MySQL? Не придется ли тогда при переносе приложения на другой компьютер устанавливать на нём СУБД для поддержки работы приложения? Если да, то есть ли другие способы работы с такой струтурой данных?

Comment: @ололо

     Нам бы схемку, аль чертёж --
     Мы бы сделали вертёж.
             (Л. Филатов)

Вы что со своим лимоном записей делать-то хотите? Поиск, последовательное чтение, добавление в хвост, произвольное обновление? А 1млн. записей -- не говорит почти ни о чём.

Comment: Зависит от того, как приложение выбирает и обновляет дынные. 

Пока же информации маловато.

Вообще-то, чем меньше в системе компонент, тем лучше.

Comment: @alexlz, фильтр по значению поля и чтение полей отфильтрованных записей, изменение полей, поиск записей по значению одного из полей.

Comment: @ололо так я Вам уже советовал ms jet -- true microsoft way. И в access'е с этой базой работать можно будет без проблем.

Comment: @ололо, а какой тип данных в полях и их средний размер?

Ну, и описали бы задачу.

Comment: @alexlz, не могу найти в нете вообще никаких примеров её использования

Comment: @ололо спрашиваем google https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=ms+jet+visual+c%2B%2B&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 , даёт кучу ссылок. В т.ч. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine

Там, среди прочих есть ссылка http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc811599.aspx (и др.)

Да по MS Jet много найти можно.

Comment: [SQLite](http://habrahabr.ru/post/149356/)

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос здесь не стоит использовать СУБД или нет. Если бы записей было пара сотен - я бы еще подумал надо не надо. А тут мильон - это немного, но вполне достаточно чтобы похоронить неопытного разработчика.

Есть 2 основных паттерна использования БД в приложениях:

1. Традиционный, где СУБД находится удаленно от собственно приложения (как правило на физически другом сервере)
2. СУБД встроено в приложение.

Не распространяясь в теоретические изыски отмечу, что ваш случай - это случай №2 и соответственно надо смотреть в сторону embedded/встроенных СУБД. Простейший их обзор [приведен в Википедии](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database). Сейчас самым модным встроенным СУБД является SQLite - я бы не стал отходить от тренда... - ну разве что посмотрел в сторону моего любимого HSQLDB (Hypersonic SQLDB).

В общем при использовании встроенных БД проблема переноса уходит - инсталлятор всегда можно настроить так чтобы на месте разворачивалась переносимая СУБД автоматом подцепленная к аппе.

**Update:** Про *Microsoft way* - я бы посмотрел в сторону MS Access - миллион записей вполне по плечу, поддержка MS Jet обеспечена - что еще надо?

Comment: @Barmaley ♦ Ну для некоторых работ по мульону записей вполне подойдут berkley db или ещё какие хеш-таблицы.

Comment: А std::vector или list для такой задачи не котируется? В принципе, можно уложиться в не очень большой объем оперативы и скорость будет не фатально низкая... Зато все стандартными средствами.

Comment: @gecube а откуда этот мульон загрузить в `list`? Из БД :)